Impact of Enabling Enterprise Territory Management in Org
I've been exploring Enterprise Territory Management, which I've successfully enabled in my organization.
I've configured territory settings, created models, types, and territories, and even set up an assignment rule. Upon running the rule, I confirmed that accounts matching the conditions were appropriately added to their respective territories.
However, despite these configurations, I haven't observed any noticeable impacts on existing organizations, contacts, or opportunities.
Can I know of any impacts there would be after this option is enabled?

Did you run the assignment rules for each territory?  That's the only way to get your existing records assigned.

@DavidCheng Yes I did and I got the records assigned to the territory. May I know any impacts here because there are many existing records.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
